# SQL. Convert datediff hours to dd.hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got some code that generates hours between an oldest record in the table `(MIN)` and `getdate()`, and am using

```
CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,MIN(OLDESTRECORD),GETDATE()),0),108)
```

to get the `HH:MM:SS`, but when the hours is more than 24 hours it just shows the hours part. i.e. 30 hours difference shows as 6 hours... how do I get it to show `dd.hh:mm:ss` i.e. 1.06:00:00

Comment: is this MySQL or sql server? both are different products which can have differing answers

Comment: it looks like he's got something that does work in SQL server - I'm not sure if the CONVERT would be in that format in MYSQL

Comment: Sorry SQL Server - MS SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

watch out for the case where the 'time' in the start day has not been reached in the end date

```
 select cast(DATEDIFF(SECOND,MIN(OLDESTRECORD),GETDATE()) /  86400  as varchar(4)) + '.' +  CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,MIN(OLDESTRECORD),GETDATE()) % 86400 ,0),108)
```